# Web scraping with Kimurai gem

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, kimurai

I am doing some web scraping with the [Kimurai Ruby gem](https://github.com/vifreefly/kimuraframework). I have this script that works great:

```
require 'kimurai'

class SimpleSpider < Kimurai::Base
  @name = "simple_spider"
  @engine = :selenium_chrome
  @start_urls = ["https://apply.workable.com/taxjar/"]

  def parse(response, url:, data: {})
    # Update response to current response after interaction with a browser
    count = 0
    # browser.click_button "Show more"
    doc = browser.current_response
    returned_jobs = doc.css('.careers-jobs-list-styles__jobsList--3_v12')
    returned_jobs.css('li').each do |char_element|
        # puts char_element
        title = char_element.css('a')[0]['aria-label']
        link = "https://apply.workable.com" + char_element.css('a')[0]['href']

        #click on job link and get description
        browser.visit(link)
        job_page = browser.current_response
        description = job_page.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]').text

        puts '*******'
        puts title
      puts link
        puts description
        puts count += 1
    end
    puts "There are #{count} jobs total"
  end
end

SimpleSpider.crawl!
```

However, I'm wanting this all to return an array of objects...or jobs in this case. I'd like to create a jobs array in the parse method and do something like `jobs << [title, link, description, company]` inside the `returned_jobs` loop and have that get returned when I call `SimpleSpider.crawl!` but that doesn't work.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is a [parse method](https://github.com/vifreefly/kimuraframework#parsemethod_name-url-config--method) that allows a value to be returned. Here is working example:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'kimurai'

class TaxJar < Kimurai::Base
  @name = "tax_jar"
  @engine = :selenium_chrome
  @start_urls = ["https://apply.workable.com/taxjar/"]

  def parse(response, url:, data: {})
  jobs = Array.new

    doc = browser.current_response
    returned_jobs = doc.css('.careers-jobs-list-styles__jobsList--3_v12')
    returned_jobs.css('li').each do |char_element|
      title = char_element.css('a')[0]['aria-label']
      link = "https://apply.workable.com" + char_element.css('a')[0]['href']

      #click on job link and get description
      browser.visit(link)
      job_page = browser.current_response
      description = job_page.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]').text
      company = 'TaxJar'
      puts "title is: #{title}, link is: #{link}, \n description is: #{description}"
      jobs << [title, link, description, company]
    end
    return jobs
  end
end

jobs = TaxJar.parse!(:parse, url: "https://apply.workable.com/taxjar/")
puts jobs.inspect
```

If you are scraping JS websites, this gem seems pretty robust compared with others (waitr/selenium) I have tried.

Answer (score 4):

You can slightly modify your code like this:

```
class SimpleSpider < Kimurai::Base
  @name = "simple_spider"
  @engine = :selenium_chrome
  @start_urls = ["https://apply.workable.com/taxjar/"]

  def parse(response, url:, data: {})
    # Update response to current response after interaction with a browser
    count = 0
    # browser.click_button "Show more"
    doc = browser.current_response
    returned_jobs = doc.css('.careers-jobs-list-styles__jobsList--3_v12')

    jobs = []
    returned_jobs.css('li').each do |char_element|
        # puts char_element
        title = char_element.css('a')[0]['aria-label']
        link = "https://apply.workable.com" + char_element.css('a')[0]['href']

        #click on job link and get description
        browser.visit(link)
        job_page = browser.current_response
        description = job_page.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]').text

        jobs << [title, link, description]
    end

    puts "There are #{jobs.count} jobs total"
    puts jobs
  end
end
```

I am not sure about the company as I don't see that variable in your code. However, you can see the idea to call an array above and work on that.

Here is part of output running in terminal:

[image: Screen]

I also have a blog post [here](https://medium.com/@lalusaud_84531/web-scraper-application-with-ruby-on-rails-864dfaae6270) about how to use Kimurai framework from Ruby on Rails application.

Comment: Lalu this won't work. When I call SimpleSpider.crawl! the jobs array is nil.

Comment: @MarkLocklear it is working for me. I have updated the screen with the output coming to Jobs array.

Comment: Nice blog post! I may be missing something, and I can't quite see everything you are doing in the terminal, I was not seeing anything being returned after running the .crawl! method.